# Função para ler arquivo via ODBC

Tags: sql, r, odbc

Olá, deve ser um problema muito simples, mas já procurei bastante e não consegui achar uma solução para a minha dúvida.

Minha configuração é:

```
    R version 3.3.1 (2016-06-21)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Portuguese_Brazil.1252  LC_CTYPE=Portuguese_Brazil.1252    LC_MONETARY=Portuguese_Brazil.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                      
[5] LC_TIME=Portuguese_Brazil.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_3.3.1  rpart_4.1-10
```

Fiz uma função para importar arquivos via ODBC de um banco ACCESS, como se segue:

```
importa.sql <- function(arquivo)
  {
    library(RODBC) # carrega pacote para conectar ao ODBC
    con <- odbcConnect("CarteiraComercialLocal") # cria a conexão local
    qry<-paste("(","SELECT * FROM ",arquivo,")")
    arquivo <- sqlQuery(con,qry,stringsAsFactors=FALSE) # Importa o arquivo para o data.frame do R
  }
```

Testei cada linha da função e o código funciona perfeitamente. O problema é que quando rodo a função, o arquivo não fica disponível no R, mas não dá erro nenhum!!!

Alguém sabe o que pode estar acontecendo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você não está retornando o arquivo na função...

Acrescente uma linha no final da função `return(arquivo)`.

Quando chamar a função use `dados <- importa.sql()`

Comment: Obrigado @Daniel, eu já havia testado isso, mas ela retorna o resultado na console. Eu gostaria que ele criasse o data.frame e ficasse disponível para utilização em outro procedimento. Os arquivos são muito grandes e fica inviável dessa forma. Alguma outra ideia?

Comment: Veja a edição. O jeito certo de fazer funções no R é que elas retornem um objeto e não que elas modifiquem o ambiente global. Você pode usar o operador `<<-` também tipo `arquivo <<- sqlQuery...` mas isso não é recomendado.